# React-native: position elements in the center and flex-end

Tags: react-native, flexbox

Is it possible to have the following layout (without resorting to absolute positioning)?

```
|...........centreElement.......RightElement|
```

So as if the justifyContent was 'space-between' but without the first element. I also thought to 'justifyContent: 'centre'' and then try 'justifySelf: 'flex-end' on the RightElement but this property does not exist.

```
<View styles={styles.container}>
  <Text>centreElement</Text>
  <Text>RightElement</Text>
</View>

container: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is mistake in your code please update code from `<View styles={styles.container}>` to `<View style={styles.container}>`

Please try the following code:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
     <View style={{ flex: 1 }} />
     <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Text>centreElement</Text>
     </View>
     <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Text>RightElement</Text>
     </View>
</View>
```

Answer (score 1):

An ideal solution without **using absolute**. The `CentreElement` text might not comes at the center, but without `absolute`, you cannot align it either, since you are not giving the content to take up the `100%` width which is needed to rightly align the content to center. Following steps can give you the satisfying results:

- Just give out `flexDirection: 'row'` to the container
- Give both the text **CentreElement** and **RightElement** `50%` width
- Align both of them to `right`, and done!!

**Code:**

```js
export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {/* Txt container*/}
      <View style={styles.textContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>
          CentreElement
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.text}>
          RightElement
        </Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  textContainer: {
    width: '100%',
    flexDirection: 'row'
  },
  text: {
    textAlign: 'right', 
    width: '50%', 
    fontSize: 16, 
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  }
});
```

**Result:**

[image: Resultant Screenshot]